# Google Spreadsheet script using SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), changing to work in other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am using a script with Google Spreadsheet to send an email. My file has 3 sheets, this one that sends email, is named "EMAIL". The code to send is this:

```
function sendEmails() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var emailAddress = 'destination@domain.com'; 
    var subject = 'Subject BlaBlaBla';  
    var dados = sheet.getRange ("B2:M10").getValues(); //range with mail content
    var message2 = getTable(dados); //format the range in html table

    //Envia o email em formato HTML
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message2
    });
}
```

I have a button in "EMAIL" sheet that start sendEmails(). It works fine.

My problem is:

I wanna put a button in other sheet, called "2019" that should start the email sending too, without having the sheet "EMAIL" active. What should i change on this code to work this function sendEmails() without having the "EMAIL" sheet active?

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

I have to change to something that keeps this function working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to run the function of `sendEmails()` by giving the sheet name.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the script is run for the sheet name of `2019`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

To:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("2019");
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, when the active sheet is `EMAIL` and `2019`, the script is run.

#### Modified script:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var sheetNames = ["EMAIL", "2019"];

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheetNames.indexOf(sheet.getSheetName()) > 0) {
    var emailAddress = 'destination@domain.com'; 
    var subject = 'Subject BlaBlaBla';  
    var dados = sheet.getRange ("B2:M10").getValues(); //range with mail content
    var message2 = getTable(dados); //format the range in html table

    //Envia o email em formato HTML
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: emailAddress,
      subject: subject,
      htmlBody: message2
    });
  }
}
```

#### References:

- [getSheetByName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetname)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: thanks a lot again! but is there a way not writing the sheet´s name? i´d like to work on any sheet in the file
var sheet = "EMAIL";
or specifying the name of the sheet that contains the function data

Comment: sorry, i think this will work

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMAIL");

Comment: it works! Great!
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("EMAIL");

Comment: @Roberto Junior Thank you for quick reply. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.